# Rescale the mainwindow and its contents to fit in different screens. Qt Creator

Tags: android, c++, qt

I have finished a project in Qt creator. I would like to port this to an Android device. The problem I am having is the scaling of my mainwindow and its contents. How can I rescale the mainwindow and all its contents according to the screen size? I have tried QWidget::resize() function. It resizes the mainwindow. Although I like to change the window sizes and all its contents dynamically once the user changes the size of the screen or once the application is running on a different screen resolution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you hardcode the widget sizes ?

Comment: No, I did not specify any sizes for the mainwindow and its contents in my code.

Comment: where did you specify them ? designer ? that is hard coding, too.. you need to use as much layouts & spacers as you can. If you still need to scale something according to desktop resolution use QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry to find a scaling factor and scale the widgets as such